# Custom cumulative sum with decay factor

Tags: performance, r, inline, cumsum

I am trying to optimize the following code.

```
dim <- c(10000,100)

m <- matrix(sample(0:10, prod(dim), replace = TRUE), nrow = dim[1], ncol = dim[2])

system.time({

  output <- matrix(0, nrow = dim[1], ncol = dim[2])

  for (i in 1:dim[1]){        
    output[i,1] <- m[i,1]       
    for (j in 2:dim[2]){          
      output[i,j] <- output[i, j-1] * 0.5 + m[i,j]          
    }        
  }
})
```

Conceptually, it is quite similar to a simple cumulative sum:

```
system.time({

  output <- matrix(0, nrow = dim[1], ncol = dim[2])

  for (i in 1:dim[1]){       
      output[i,] <- cumsum(m[i,])        
  }
})
```

The problem is, the first part of the code is about 100 times slower. Is there any way to build a customized version of cumsum() that would do the trick ?

Comment: Ignoring the matrix for the moment, just concentrating on the i=th row, which I'll name as a vector `rowi`,   I think  `mtail <- rowi * 2^(-1*(0:length(rowi))) `  will produce values such that `outputi <-cumsum(mtail)` are what you want.   I'll try  to gin up a test case if nobody beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is exactly the same as generating a AR(1) model with coefficient 0.5. You can use the `filter` function to generate the data. `filter` also support higher order recursion, convolution or    mixture of them(think about the ARMA model). You may have a look of`convolve` for other convolutions. Also, you could compiler your code to speed up the loop. In my code, complied loop and uncompiled loop code is about 111 and 162 times slower than filter respectively.

```
library(compiler)
library(rbenchmark)

CustomCumsum<-function(x,alpha){
out<-x[1]
for(i in 2:length(x))
    out[i] <- out[i-1]*alpha+x[i]
out
}

compiledCustomCumsum<-cmpfun(CustomCumsum)

FilterCustomCumsum<-function(x,alpha) as.numeric(filter(x,alpha, method = "recursive"))

x<-rnorm(1000)
# Test whether they are the same
identical(compiledCustomCumsum(x,0.5) , FilterCustomCumsum(x,0.5) )

benchmark(
CustomCumsum=CustomCumsum(x,0.5),compiledCustomCumsum=compiledCustomCumsum(x,0.5),          FilterCustomCumsum=FilterCustomCumsum(x,0.5)
)
```

output:

```
                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 compiledCustomCumsum          100    8.89  111.125      8.78     0.01         NA        NA
1         CustomCumsum          100   13.02  162.750     11.84     0.50         NA        NA
3   FilterCustomCumsum          100    0.08    1.000      0.08     0.00         NA        NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing my custom cumulative function in C is really much faster than everything else:

```
sign <- signature(x="numeric", n="integer", d="numeric")

code <- "
  for (int i=1; i < *n; i++) {
    x[i] = x[i-1]*d[0] + x[i];
  }"

c_fn <- cfunction(sign,
                  code,
                  convention=".C"
)

CCustomCumsum <- function(vector, decay){
  c_fn(x=vector, n=length(vector), d=decay)$x
}
```

Running Julian's benchmark with:

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
# Test whether they are the same
identical(compiledCustomCumsum(x,0.5) , FilterCustomCumsum(x,0.5) )

benchmark(
  CustomCumsum=CustomCumsum(x,0.5),
  compiledCustomCumsum=compiledCustomCumsum(x,0.5),
  FilterCustomCumsum=FilterCustomCumsum(x,0.5),
  CCustomCumsum = CCustomCumsum(x, 0.5)  
)
```

, I get:

```
                  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4        CCustomCumsum          100   0.002      1.0     0.002    0.000          0         0
2 compiledCustomCumsum          100   0.631    315.5     0.536    0.095          0         0
1         CustomCumsum          100   0.931    465.5     0.882    0.046          0         0
3   FilterCustomCumsum          100   0.036     18.0     0.033    0.003          0         0
```